# Can we condition on an event and a random variable at the same time?

Tags: probability

Suppose that $X \sim N(0,1)$ and $Y|X \sim N(0,X^2)$, i.e. condition on X, Y has a normal with mean 0 and variance $x^2$.

I am only interested on the event: $A = \{X > 1\}$.

Then condition on this set A (i.e. only consider those outcomes that X > 1), I want to calculate the conditional probability: $Pr( Y > 1 | X)$

So I'm not sure if I can write it as $Pr(Y > 1 | X, A)$?
Does it make sense conditioning on both RV X and event A?

Also, how would you calculate this probability?

Note that without conditioning on A, I know that:
$Pr( Y > 1 | X) = 1 - \Phi(\frac{1}{X})$

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your event $A$ makes minimal difference.  You still have  $Pr(Y \gt 1\mid X=x, A) = 1 - \Phi(\frac{1}{x})$.  Without $A$ you can abbreviate to  $Pr(Y \gt 1\mid X) = 1 - \Phi(\frac{1}{X})$ as a function of the random variable $X$ and so a random variable itself.  The difference is that $Pr(Y \gt 1\mid X=x, A) $ is meaningless for $x \le 1$ while $Pr(Y \gt 1\mid X=x) $ is not.  You might take this to mean that $Pr(Y \gt 1\mid X, A) = 1 - \Phi(\frac{1}{X})$ is not actually a function of $X$ as there are values of $X$ which cannot have the conditional probability calculated.